# Dynamically changing the array size of an element of data structure in C

Tags: c

I am new to C programming. Please excuse if this question is not appropriate. I have been struggling to dynamically change the size of a variable inside the structure (not the struct itself). Let's say I have a struct called dist1 like the code below. I want to pass this structure into a function and dynamically change the size of test1. Is this even possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct distance
{
    double *test1;
    double *test2;
};


int main()
{
    struct distance dist1;
    add(&dist1); 

    return 0;
}

void add(struct distance *d3) 
{
     // I want to dynamically change the size of "test1" to let's say test1(50)
     // Is this possible?
}
```

Comment: (1) They aren't arrays to begin with. Change them to `double*` (2) Dynamically sizing arrays at runtime is done with malloc/realloc. (3) You need to declare add() before its first use.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the size of test1? distance is a struct containing 2 doubles test1 and test2. the size of test1, test2 are fixed. If you want to dynamically change their size, use a pointer `double*`.

Comment: It is not possible to change the size of anything in C. A `struct distance` always has the same size (probably 2 times the size of a `double`)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker sorry I forgot to write it as double* . Can I change the size of test1 with malloc inside my function?

Comment: @nabil.douss sorry I forgot to write them as double*

Comment: Use malloc() the first time, then realloc() to change.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I have tried it inside the main() and it actually works. But I am struggling to do this inside the function.

Comment: Put what you tried in the question and then we can point out what's wrong.

Comment: What's the difference? Malloc is malloc. Doesn't matter where you call it from.

Comment: In C, once an _array_ is defined, its size cannot change.  Code can allocated various amounts of memory for a _pointer_, yet a _pointer_ is not an _array_ and an _array_ is not a _pointer_.

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi In C, what you call ["static array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917280/dynamically-changing-the-array-size-of-an-element-of-data-structure-in-c/48917326?noredirect=1#comment84844374_48917326) is an _array_.  What you call "array with dynamic size" is a _pointer_ that has been assigned a value form `malloc()`.  Since an _array_ cannot change size once defined, what you need for "Dynamically changing the array size of an element of data structure" is a _pointer_ that gets re-assigned to various results of `malloc()`, `realloc()`, etc.

Comment: @chux Got your point. However, what is the advantage of your method compare to what I used above?

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi  An advantage to an _array_ is that `sizeof` reflects the amount of data.  An _array_ like `char a[7]`, the `sizeof a` is 7.  With `char *p = malloc(some_value);` the `sizeof p` is 4, 8 or whatever the _pointer_ size.  If code needs fixed amount of data, use an _array_.   If code needs a variant amount of data, use a pointer to memory and allocate memory with `*alloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in any meaningful way. You can always have `struct distance` container pointers to double instead of doubles, and then change the size of the pointed to memory, but your goal here isn't clear so I'm not sure what use that would be.

Comment: sorry there was a typo in the code. test and test 2 are arrays.

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi `double *test2;` is a [pointer to double](https://cdecl.org/?q=double+*test2), not an _array_.

Comment: @chux malloc has been used later in the code for memory allocation.

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi `malloc()` or not, `double *test2` is still not an array.  It is a pointer.

Comment: @chux I am new to C programming and what I want to say may sound stupid. But isn't it that if you want an array with dynamic size you need to use malloc and calloc with a pointer? I know I can define a static array like double array[20] but in my code, how will you define an array instead of a pointer? Or better to ask, how will you change my code by declaring an array instead of a pointer?

Comment: This is just a question of semantics, but it's worth clarifying anyways. The definition `double *test2` defines a variable who's type is `pointer to double`. You can say that this pointer is pointing to an array of doubles, but that doesn't mean the type of test2 is an array. The meaning of what it's pointing to is up to interpretation in a way.

Comment: You can say it's pointing to an array of doubles, you can say it's pointing a single double, you can say it's pointing to a series of numbers, or you could say it's pointing to data representing your test data. All of these would be correct. But the *type* of the variable test2 isn't up to interpretation, it's a `pointer to double`. You can't define a variable with a type of a dynamically sized array. You need to define it as a pointer and point it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

The members of `struct distance` are best first initialized.

```
struct distance dist1 = { NULL, NULL };
```

To change the the number of elements allocated, use `realloc()`.  Pass to it `d3->test1` and the number of bytes needed.  If the value returned is not `NULL`, the re-allocation succeeded and code should use that.  Research `realloc()` for more details.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void add(struct distance *d3) {
  // I want to dynamically change the size of "test1" to let's say test1(50)
  size_t new_element_count = 50;
  void *tmp = realloc(d3->test1, sizeof *(d3->test1) * new_element_count);
  if (tmp == NULL && new_element_count > 0) {
    Handle_OutOfMemory();
  } else {
    d3->test1 = tmp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get this run. I really appreciate everybody's help and time. You guys are amazing!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct distance
{
    double *test1;
    double *test2;
};


void add(struct distance *dist1) ;


int main()
{
    struct distance dist1;

    dist1.test1 = (double *) malloc(5*sizeof(double));
    dist1.test1[4] = 14.22;
    printf("dist1.test1[4] from main() = %f\n", dist1.test1[4]);

    add(&dist1); 

    printf("dist1.test2[3] from main() = %f\n", dist1.test2[3]);

    return 0;
}

void add(struct distance *dist1) 
{
     printf("dist1.test1[4] from add() = %f\n", (*dist1).test1[4]);

     (*dist1).test2 = (double *) malloc(10*sizeof(double));
     (*dist1).test2[3] = 14.67;
     printf("dist1.test2[3] from add() = %f\n", (*dist1).test2[3]);
}
```

Comment: You can use `dist1->test1` instead of `(*dist1).test1`. 
Also, you have a memory leak here. The original malloc in main was never freed. This is a perfect place to use realloc though, it's more efficient and will solve the memory leak as a bonus. 
Replace the malloc line in your add function with:
`dist1->test2 = (double*)realloc(dist1->test2, 10*sizeof(double))`

Comment: @cmtm I used malloc in main() for test1. The malloc in add() is for test2. That is why I did not use realloc. I am also aware of dist1->test1 but is there any reason why I shouldn't use (*dist1).test1 ?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that one was for test1 and the other for test2.
The arrow operator is generally considered to be more readable than dereferencing between parentheses. These cases are fairly simple, so you won't see a big difference, but consider this: `my_func((*st).p1, (int) (*st).p2)` vs. `my_func(st->p1, (int) st->p2)`. Most would consider the latter much better.